# VBA Selenium Chrome launch gives waiting for OLE error

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ole

The selenium code launches Chrome without any issues on my laptop.
But when deployed on two different servers, it gives waiting on OLE action error intermittently.

I can see the `chromedriver.exe` in task manager, but Chrome doesn't open.

Its really annoying, I tried all the quick fixes like ignore the DDE, uncheck compatibility mode, plugins.
Even placed `chromedriver` in `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application`
and
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`

I am also triggering `RunCleaner.vbs`, `StartChromeDebug.vbs` from `C:\Program Files\SeleniumBasic\Scripts`
before triggering my actual code.

But nothing seems to be fixing this issue.
Could someone shed some light on what else needs to be done to avoid the OLE error?